# ARIMA model for stock market data

Tags: arima, finance

I have a finance data set (2 stock market data sets, e.g., Google, Apple) for four years. I would like to fit the ARIMA model to the data. After that, I would like to fit the GARCH model to the residual values. My question is,

Must I assume each year for each stock market as a univariate data set? In other words, must I fit the univariate ARIMA model for each year of each stock market? For example, the first ARIMA model will be for the first year of Google. Hence, I need to fit 8 ARIMA models in total. Is that correct? if not, could you please explain to me why?

Comment: two univariate ARIMAs- google, apple

Comment: Could you explain why you believe that you should fit a different model every year? It's not actually necessary and it's not what most people would try first.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Thank you for your comment. I am new to the area and read some papers that fit the ARIMA model to each year as a univariate model. That why I wonder is this must be done or not.

Comment: Could you reference those papers? They may have had a particular reason to do this. But no, it is not the case that you *must* do this.

Comment: *"I would like to fit the ARIMA model to the data"* why?

Answer (score 0):

ARIMA is a univariate model, so you need to fit 1 ARIMA model for each asset. If not explicitly stated otherwise, you should fit each ARIMA to the whole 4 years dataset. So you get 2 univariate ARIMAs for Google and Apple as Shibamouli Lahiri  stated.

For the typical financial daily/monthly data you should get a result that ARIMA(0,1,0) is optimal and your price returns are just white noise and your price is brownian motion. So for the second stage you will just fit GARCH for the original returns. You need to fit 2 GARCH models, one for each asset